# How to create proper path matching redirects in NextJS

Tags: redirect, next.js

I'm in the process migrating from a WordPress site to a new site built in NextJS. On the old site, there are over a thousand posts which have been indexed at `domain/[slug]`, where the new site has all blog posts available at `domain/posts/[slug]`. I tested a path matching redirect that worked for the blog posts, but it's firing off for everything. So if someone were to visit `domain/about`, they would be redirected to "domain/posts/about".

Any suggestions on how to limit this behavior to only posts?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? What would a post's slug look like?

Comment: Hi @juliomalves, I chose to change routing where all posts are available off index. This was for SEO purposes and felt it was a better option than trying to redirect/rewrite, which felt more like a band-aid than a proper solution to the problem. Thanks though!